# How do I store my new built data structure? C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, save, store

I have gained lots of knowledge about algorithms and data structures and how to apply them in different problems. They say: "use a binary search tree (BST) on problem X", but never what to do when the tree is constructed.

Now, for this question, I have built a BST over some objects holding some values. Also, the search function is in place. So, I compile, insert the objects, and do a search on a string. However, all this gets destroyed after the program termination and the process repeats. My intention is to keep the tree stored at some place, and be able to search in the stored BST as I want.

So, how do I keep my BST at some place and do searches on the already built tree? That is, I don't want to built the tree every time. I am planning to built a large tree that I want to have the option to search in.

**Tedious example:**

```
int main() {    
    const string s1 = "Volkswagen";
    const string s2 = "Ferrari";
    const string s3 = "Whatever";
    
    Car* g1 = new Car(s1);
    Car* g2 = new Car(s2);
    Car* g3 = new Car(s3);
    BinTree t; //construct empty tree and add to it in the following 3 lines
    t.insert(g1);
    t.insert(g2);
    t.insert(g3);
    Gene* found_gene; //declare
    found_gene = t.search("Rugbrødsbil") //assign the found object for later use. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly you'd like to write the BST to disk and load it back up anytime the program starts?

C++ doesn't really have a built in way to do this, so you'd need to write custom logic that allows the BST to serialize and deserialize itself (to/from a string for example), and then save that data to disk (you can probably google around for disk I/O in C++), that way when the program starts up it can read the string back and recreate the tree.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/ here is a page I found which may help you out with specifics!

Comment: i'll check it out and will get back

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search the tree in-place from solid state memory like you suggest, you need to find a way to store it so you can retain the needed information for traversal. I had a similar problem to solve with a B+ tree I made. A simple way that comes to mind is using the fseek library function or something similar and storing your nodes in a binary file formatted sort of like this:

For an example tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

and nodes like this:

```
struct Node {
    someType *data;  //note that this must be a pointer
    Node *left, *right;
};
```

You'd have the representation in the file look like this

```
1->data line #, 2, 3;
2->data line #, nil, nil;
3->data line #, nil, nil;
```

You could change the delimiter and you'd have to pick a way to store nil in the file, but this is the basic idea. For a search you'd start at line 0 and read the node data, which would be stored elsewhere in the file, determine which child to go to, and fseek to the line of the child, similar to the flow of a BST in memory. Like I mentioned in the comment, data would probably need to be a pointer so you can use a line number in the binary file. You'd probably need to store the actual data somewhere else in the file or in another file since you may not know the memory size (and you'd have parsing problems if it contained the delimiter) of the data.

Let me know if I can clarify this better.

Comment: Interesting. So how do you construct the order in the file? just using any tree-traversal?

What if I had a bitvector I wanted to do some operation on before knowing whether I should go to right or left. Like the following. Can I then take out the value from the file and do operation on it? 


`struct Node {
    someType *data; // note that this must be a pointer
    Node *left, *right;
    bitset<10> foo;
};`


Does my question make sense?

Comment: You could absolutely read the data from the bit vector from your file into memory and perform your operation first. You could either figure out a way to store the vector in the same entry as the right and left line numbers that allowed you to reliably parse it, or store a line number, filename + line number to the location of the vector elsewhere. As far as constructing the order, it doesn't really matter as long as you have the line number of the root saved somewhere. I would just use a pre-order traversal to initially populate the file.

Comment: Hi Kyle. Sorry for the late response. I have now tried to go with your solution which seems nice. However...

I have trouble finding out how to use fseek as suggested. How do you know where in the file to jump to using fseek? Each node must know where in the text file its children are located, and this is really difficult to solve :\