# How to serialize a binary tree to a file in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, binary-tree, fseek

I want to serialize a binary tree into a .txt file. I am traversing the tree using bfs, to be able to just multiply by 2 (or 2+1 for right child) to jump to a left child of a node, and I want to write to the file in that order. I am planning to use fseek (C++) to point the cursor to the location in the file where a child begins. Ideally I want to have the location for the childrens start location in each parent. I want to write my tree to a file, so I'll be able to search for a given node in the file. I don't want to deserialize it.

Fx. below is a depiction on how I want it. node1 has the start position for it's left and right children (note that they are just random numbers for illustrative purposes), and with this I should be able to set the pointer using fseek and read the childrens data quickly. However, I have not been able to find out how? Is there a smart way of doing this? I.e. to find the location for the children in the file and add those to each parent.

Binary tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

File:

```
//a txt file where each node stores the positions of its children in the file. 
//Format is: (node number: some data, left child position, right child position)
node1: data, 13, 26;
node2: data, 50, 80;
node3: data, 100, 150;
...
```

Comment: If you use a text file like this, no, you cannot just determine the position of a node without reading the content that comes before; you can make a guess, but you won't be able to calculate the exact location. `node1: data, 2, 3;` has a different length than `node1: data, 20000, 30000;`, so you won't be able to determine the exact location unless you somehow manage to keep the length of a line constant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why SWIG?

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any code and seems like it might fit better over at https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Are you specifically asking about ```FSeek()``` functionality?

Comment: @fabian good point. I was thinking about this, by adding leading zeros and to the positions so keep it constant. I just think it's messy this way.

Comment: @Skewjo, someone suggested to use fseek(). But I am open to use other methods.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I will check them out. Not much information about RPCXDR though

Comment: https://www.onc-rpc-xdr.com/

Comment: You may want to use [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to generate the parsing code

Comment: @Kyle suggested fseek in this question where he used it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923382/10636463

Comment: Seems you want to do a pre-order traversal, but I don't think your strategy for serialising and using `fseek` is a good idea. Common text-based serialisation of a binary tree is a [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). You could adapt it so each not either has inline data or an index to a lookup table with the node data.

Comment: I don't think preorder will do the trick. I'll check S-expressions out.

Comment: There's a millions of years old text document out there somewhere on Huffman compression that ends with a brutally compact way to store the tree. But it's a binary format, not text. You can't guess, you have to load the tree to traverse it. I'm yet to hear of a tree structure that this doesn't hold true for. If you could predict, the tree would be holding redundant info. ;)

Comment: Does it have to be a flat file? Could you used the directory structure of the file system to mirror the branches of your tree?

Comment: @Galik, I have several hundred thousands of nodes. Wouldn't it result in a big mess? or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't know all your requirements, but you say you want "to search for a given node". It struck me that filesystems are likely optimized for traversing directory tree structures as, at the end of the day, the raw filesystem is just flat data with a tree structure imposed on it. So you might potentially have a directory to represent each node and let the file system find specific nodes using its full (relative) path-name.

Comment: If your `Node` is always the same size, you could use the file position for the links.  The file should be open in binary mode.

Comment: I going to do this instead: write the tree to a file and then just ifstream the file into a vector. Then I can do search on the vector. It seems like my way of wanting to do it, as stated in the question, might not be possible afterall.

Comment: You might consider using [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)